# VKNet. Получение списка аудио.Сохранение аудио

Tags: c#, vkontakte-api, vknet

В связи с блокировкой методов Аудио в вк.
Есть ли способы получить список всех аудио пользователя и последовательно загрузить.
Кроме http://api.xn--41a.ws/

Comment: Кроме как авторизоваться пользователем - нет.

Comment: по токену не подойдет?

Answer (score 0):

Через API vk.com этого сделать нельзя, как и через VKNet, но никто ещё не отменял парсинг. Можно использовать браузер в формах, чтобы авторизовать пользователя и получить исходный код страницы его аудиозаписей. Или же вручную, без браузера, составить HTTP запрос для авторизации и запрос на переход на страницу с музыкой.